# str_get_html with curl wont work

Tags: php, html, string, curl, get

When I get a response from curl I get a html in a string format, the following will work:

```
$html = str_get_html('<tr class="color_1">
        <td class="texto" width="62px">
           <div class="texto">
                154848
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="texto" width="54px">
                <div class="texto">
                        1547
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>');

foreach($html->find('tr td div.texto') as $element)
{
    echo $element->innertext;
}
```

but when I change in the str_get_html the file:

```
$html = str_get_html($table[0]);

foreach($html->find('tr td div.texto') as $element)
{
    echo $element->innertext;
}
```

$table[0] is only the html that contains the table, I get the next error:Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in

Curl code

```
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_URL, $urlFechas);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POST,true);
//Le vamos a enviar parámetros posts
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdataFechas);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
//Para poder guardar el html
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$url_destino2=curl_getinfo($handler, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
//Executamos
$response2 = curl_exec ($handler);

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

//print "SISI";
$arrayHtml=explode('<table class="list">',$response2);
$tabla=explode('</table>',$arrayHtml[1]);
```

Comment: I had the same issue, are you able to just use file_get_contents(); ?

Comment: can you put your curl code in your question?

Comment: It is quite clear that `$html[0]` does _not_ contain exactly the string you assume it does. So the question is: what _does_ it contain?

Comment: Question edited, you mean $table[0]  ?it contains a string and the structure of <tr><td><div> etc

Comment: `$tabla` != `$table`